# openshift multi node architechture

Tags: openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

How does openshift multi node architecture work in V3 version? Does all pods gets replicated across nodes or it only gets replicated if one node goes down?

Let's say I have one master and 3 nodes, in which node application pod gets resided?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a pod directly, it will get assigned to a single machine.  OpenShift uses "replication controllers" from Kubernetes to create N copies of a pod and ensure they are running, and "deployment configs" to handle rolling out changes (changing a deployment config creates a new replication controller with the new changes, and the old replication controller is scaled down).  Both replication controllers and deployment configs have a scale number that is used to control the number of copies.  Pods from the same replication controller are automatically spread across different nodes.